# Pass a variable as parameter on restart (from last run to next run) in pm2

Tags: node.js, pm2

Is there a way to pass a variable to define behaviour of the restart (if it is a crash or just because of files change on watch). Such variable passed as a parameter would be easily read by pm2 to behave accordingly in the next start.

**Scenario**
On start of `www` by pm2, The app checks if environment is fine (DB is up and schema is well defined, also checks some other services), more importantly **it seeds development data into the database and loads so much data into memory**.

If the app crashes and cannot restart because of some serious error (compilation error for example), I would like to reload everything. Otherwise, I would not seed data into DB again, I would reload the app just loading data into memory. I know this would easily implemented only if I know what happened before.

Obviously, I can cache to some file the exit status or something, and check on startup that file for the flag. But I would like to know for sure if PM2 offers such thing via environment variables or something similar.